Question about the change of basis matrix
I want to ask a question to all of you to see if I can clarify this concept. If I have two basis, $b_1$ and $b_2$ that are not the canonical basis, i can find the change of basis matrix from $b_1$ to $b_2$ by expressing the $b_2$ basis vectors as linear combination of the b1 basis vectors and use the coefficients that I find as columns of my matrix.
With that matrix I can change the coordinates of a vector expressed in one basis to coordinates in the other basis. But my question is, what will I obtain when I multiply the change of basis matrix with the vectors of the basis $b_1$? Not the coordinates of a vector with respect to $b_1$, but with the vectors of the basis $b_1$.
Maybe this is a dumb question but I am approaching linear algebra by myself and I am confused about this argument. I hope I explained myself well. Thanks to everyone in advance.

There is nothing wrong with your English but the post is still confusing. A specific example could greatly help to know what we are talking about.

Yes, sprry for my confusion. Let s say i have two basis: b1: (1,1) (2,3) and b2: (2,1) (1,5). I can find a change of basis matrix from b1 to b2 by expressing each of the two vectors of b2 as linear combination of the b1 vectors. What happens if I multiply the obtained change of basis matrix with the two vectors of b1 ((1,1), (2,3))?

you found $M$ such that $B_2 = B_1 M$. This matrix takes a vector $v$ expressed in the basis $B_2$ and maps it to the corresponding vector in the basis $B_1$. If you multiply $M$ by a vector of $B_1$ doesn't really give you anything that you can interpret

You may not get the answer you are expecting. Remember, the basis vector $(1,1)$ is expressed as $(1,0)$ in its own coordinates. Likewise, $(2,3)$ is expressed as $(0,1)$ in $b_1$. Also, to get a vector in terms of $b_2$ from a vector in terms of $b_1$, we must use the inverse transformation because the points in the space look like they have undergone the inverse transformation from the point of view of the new coordinate system.

Remember, the basis vector (1,1)
is expressed as (1,0)
in its own coordinates. Likewise, (2,3)
is expressed as (0,1)
in b1. I can not understand this

@AlessioRotelli : In vogue, as user Exodd does, the name of a basis (set of vectors) uses capital letters

To answer your question: the result of the multiplication is meaningless. In a general setting, we deal with vectors from an abstract (finite-dimensional) vector space $V$ and write down their representations as coordinate vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. The vectors in $b_1$ and $b_2$ are members of $V$, not members of $\mathbb R^n$. You simply cannot multiply them by a matrix. The misfortune in your question is that the vector space $V$ you consider happens to be $\mathbb R^n$, so that the said multiplication is technically possible. ...

...Nevertheless, vectors in $V$ are semantically different from their representations (as coordinate vectors) in $\mathbb R^n$. The multiplication of a change-of-basis matrix with a vector (rather than coordinate vector w.r.t. the basis of the domain) has no inherent meaning.

Too long for a comment:
John Douma made a very important remark. It can in fact be quite confusing to study basis transformations when the vector space already is $\mathbb R^n$ for which we always can choose the canonical basis. I think it is healthier to study a vector space that is slightly more abstract. Let's take the space of polynomials
of degree one (for simplicity). A basis for this vector space is
$$
b_1=\{1,x\}
$$
and another basis is
$$
b_2=\{1,1-x\}\,.
$$
As linear map $T$ you can study the derivative of a function. It sends $1$ to $0$ and $x$ to $1$ and every linear combination of them to the linear combination of $0$ and $1\,.$ In the basis $b_1$ this map is represented by the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
and in $b_2$ by the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&-1\\0&0}\,.
$$
This is because in $b_1$ the components $(1,0)$ represent the polynomial $1$ and $(0,1)$ represents $x\,.$ In $b_2\,,$ $(1,0)$ represents $1$ and $(0,1)$ represents $1-x\,.$
Can you find the matrix that transforms from one basis into the other?

The OP doesn't involve nothing about linear maps and derivatives then your response adds nothing but more confusion.

@janmarqz I strongly disagree and also think that your comment is out of line. The point of this answer is showing that the OP's proposed operation can't have a reasonable meaning, and is just an accident of working with the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. If the OP were instead working with the vector space of polynomials, I doubt their question would even arise, since it doesn't make sense to multiply a matrix and a polynomial.

excuse me @ViktorVaughn , your "were instead" and the space of polynomials are out of line.

Consider this, if
$$v_1=e_1+e_2\quad \mbox{and}\quad v_2=2e_1+3e_2,\qquad (1)$$
but in other hand you set
$$w_1=2e_1+e_2\quad\mbox{and}\quad w_2=e_1+5e_2,\qquad (2)$$
then solving $e_1,e_2$ from $(1)$ we get
$$e_1=3v_1-v_2\quad \mbox{and}\quad e_2=-2v_1+v_2,\qquad (3)$$
Subb $(3)$ in $(2)$ gives
$$w_1=4v_1-v_2\quad \mbox{and}\quad w_2=-7v_1+4v_2,\qquad (4)$$
Here in $(4)$ you can see the associated matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}4&-7\\-1&4\end{array}\right]$$ which correspond
to the multiplication
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}3&-2\\-1&1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\1&5\end{array}\right].$$
Those matrices are the matrix in $(3)$, and the matrix in
$(2)$, respectively.
The knowledge of the matrix in $(4)$ allows you interpret any vector written in the base with $v_1,v_2$, in terms of the base  with $w_1,w_2$.

@Alessio Rotelli : The  vectors $e_1,e_2$ form the canonical basis which, in your convention, are $e_1=(1\ ,\ 0)$ and $e_2=(0\ ,\ 1)$.

Observe also, that the matrix in $(3)$ is the inverse matrix of the matrix in $(1)$.

$e_1=2v_1-v_2$ in (3) is wrong.

@KurtG. ok, corrected
